# database of phrases, query all entries within a given text

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a table in a sql database which contains texts like `now mix the flour into the bowl`

when a user mow enters a text i want to find these entries if the entered text contains that phrase but i.e. the user vould enter `and now mix the flour into the bowl and stir it` or something which would make it difficult to simple query for it and maybe the entered text could contain several entries which i would like to find.

how would that be possible? any ideas? i was thinking of querying for the words and try to find the oned with the most words matching but with that the entered texts could be way longer while a phrase only contains only 2 words or something.

hope that makes sense and you have an direction for me to get to a practical smart solution.

Comment: not sure if I completely understand your question. But, it sounds like you could try using a like statement. Try looking at this link: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: i am not aware of the possibility zo search the input by the wildcarded column. in my task i want to find all existing entries within a given input. `SELECT * FROM phrases WHERE 'batman loves ice cream sandwiches' CONTAINS phrase`

Comment: It seems you are looking for the exact phase so perhaps the [POSTILION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) function will work for you.  So `select * from phrases where position ( '<target phase>' in phrase) > 0; `